# How can I fix "libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format" when I'm already using freetype 2.9?

Tags: teamviewer, qt5

I finally upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. Teamviewer was working just fine in 16.04. After the upgrade when I try to launch the GUI it gives me:

```
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer: symbol lookup error: /opt/qt514/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Font_Format
```

I made sure it was already on a new enough version of freetype because of the whole FT_Get_X11_Font_Format vs FT_Get_Font_Format issue that normally causes this error.

It seems the function is available:

```
rreese@rreese-desktop:~$ sudo readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so | grep -i font_format
   195: 000000000000fc10     2 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 FT_Get_X11_Font_Format
   208: 000000000000fbe0    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 FT_Get_Font_Format
```

I tried upgrading QT thinking that might be the issue, but 5.14 gives me the same error. I'm kinda at my wits end here. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there was an old "fix" I had for FFMPEG in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ that was pointing at another lib folder. It must have taken priority because I saw when I ran teamviewer with strace it was using libfreetype.so.6 from there. Must have been a older version without the FT_Get_Font_Format because when I removed that 'fix' it grabbed the correct version and was fine.

Comment: This issue cost me several hours, though in my case, it was zoom. One other note is you may need to run `ldconfig` as root after modifying these files.